# OpenCV 3.4.1: KNearest function not found

Tags: python, opencv

I can see from the OpenCV 3.4.1 documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html) that the KNearest function exists. This is exactly my version, as you can see below:

```
 >>> import cv2
 >>> cv2.__version__
 '3.4.1'
```

However, when I run my python code it seems that it doesn't exist

```
   knn = cv2.KNearest()
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KNearest'
```

I am quite rookie on this. What have I missed? is this the correct function for such an OpenCV version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage is for the 2.x version

```
knn = cv2.KNearest() # OpenCv 2.x
```

Try this instead:

```
knn = cv2.ml.KNearest_create() # OpenCv 3.x
```

Read [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html#ab0ce3fa7a242f3418938592f4d935b81) python example from the documentation